# $\max\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ continuous for continuous functions $f_i:X \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume I have $n$ continuous functions $f_i: X \to \mathbb{R}$. Then we know that $\max\{f_1,f_2\}$ is a continuous function. We prove this most easily by seeing that $$\max\{f_1,f_2\} = \frac{1}{2}(f_1 + f_2 - |f_1 - f_2|)$$ Is there a generalization of this argument for $n$ functions? Another idea would be just induction over $n$ by using that $$\max\{f_1,\dots,f_{n + 1}\} = \max\{\max\{f_1,\dots,f_n\},f_{n + 1}\}$$ Is that also correct?

Comment: Yes,what you've written down in the second last line amounts to the inductive step, what you started out with is the first step.

Comment: Nice, thanks. First I thought there would be a nice formula of the kind for two functions, but I think it gets quite messy already for three functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your induction is fine.

Here is an alternative strategy. Think of the $f_i$ as a single continuous function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which we are then composing with the max function $\max : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Compositions of continuous functions are continuous, so the problem reduces to proving that $\max$ is continuous. But $\max$ is not only continuous, it is even [Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).